# Deleting a bunch of elements by their index?

Tags: c++, vector, remove-if

I have a

```
vector<int> myVector;
```

And I have a list of `index` to delete:

```
vector<size_t> deleteIndex;
```

Which strategy would be the most efficient to delete those indexes?

Actually one not efficient solution would be to:

```
//> sort deleteindex
auto deleted= 0;
for(auto i=0;i<deleteIndex.size();i++ {
   myVector.erase(myVector.begin()+deleteIndex[i]-deleted);
   deleted++;
}
```

Comment: Do you need to maintain the order of elements?  Do you need to do this in-place?

Comment: You can use `i` instead of `deleted`.

Comment: oil: yes the order should be kept. at pete: right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Erasing elements from a vector one-by-one is very inefficient.  This is because for every erase, it has to copy all elements down by one, then reallocate a smaller-by-one vector.

Instead, use the [erase-remove idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase-remove_idiom). This process will remove items by moving later items to replace the earlier items (it maintains original order).  After the items are removed, it will do a single erase (which is just the end of the list) to reallocate a new vector which is smaller by n items (where n is the number of items removed).

Sample Implementation:

```
template <class _FwdIt, class _FwdIt2>
_FwdIt remove_by_index(_FwdIt first, 
                       _FwdIt last,
                       _FwdIt2 sortedIndexFirst, 
                       _FwdIt2 sortedIndexLast)
{
  _FwdIt copyFrom = first;
  _FwdIt copyTo = first;
  _FwdIt2 currentIndex = sortedIndexFirst;

  size_t index = 0;
  for (; copyFrom != last; ++copyFrom, ++index)
  {
    if (currentIndex != sortedIndexLast &&
        index == *currentIndex)
    {
      // Should delete this item, so don't increment copyTo
      ++currentIndex;
      print("%d", *copyFrom);
    }
    else
    {
      // Copy the values if we're at different locations
      if (copyFrom != copyTo)
        *copyTo = *copyFrom;
      ++copyTo;
    }
  }
  return copyTo;
}
```

Sample Usage:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  std::vector<int> myVector;

  for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    myVector.push_back(i * 10);

  std::vector<size_t> deleteIndex;
  deleteIndex.push_back(3);
  deleteIndex.push_back(6);

  myVector.erase(
    remove_by_index(myVector.begin(), myVector.end(), deleteIndex.begin(), deleteIndex.end()), 
    myVector.end());

  for (std::vector<int>::iterator it = myVector.begin();
       it != myVector.end(); ++it)
  {
    printf("%d ", *it);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Gist: https://gist.github.com/eleven41/5746079
Test here: http://ideone.com/0qkDw5

Comment: @yes123 yes, hence the name of the parameters: `sortedIndexFirst` and `sortedIndexLast`.

Comment: @yes123 inside the `if` block (not the `else` block), do `print("%d", *copyFrom);`

Answer (score 1):

If you are allowed to reorder the `myVector`, just iterate through the items to delete, removing them by swapping with the last element and popping it off.

If you need to preserve order, the sort the `deleteIndex` container and do a single ordered pass to remove the element by moving other elements forward.